# Design range (sensitivity) bar intuitively

Tags: usability, website-design, forms, gui-design, web

I am building a website that includes a page that has a search input and a sensitivity bar near him that allows the users to control over the amount of results returned and their accuracy.

The site design look like this:

[image]

The sensitivity bar looks like this:

[image]

When users change the sensitivity bar, it cause the results this way:

- If he drags it to the **left**, he will receive **less** results but they will be **more** accurate.
- If he drags it to the **right**, he will receive **more** results, but they will be **less** accurate.

The current design does not convey the effect on the results when changing the sensitivity bar.

**My question is**: There is a way to pass to the users the idea that more results will come at the expense of accuracy in an efficient way?

Comment: NGAFD's answer should do the trick for this question but I have a follow-up. Any particular reason why **more results** have to be **less accurate**?

Comment: @ShreyasTripathy because this is the architecture of my system- the more less accurate the search is the more results is returned, and not always the results you wanted to.

Answer (score 2):

Aren't we back into the "why show an icon when you can simply explain what's going on" argument?

With that in-mind, this is how I would do it, if I were tackling the same thing.

[image: Search Accuracy]

Answer (score 0):

You can have a small optional popup that shows more information about what search radius is. Your users can hover (or click) a 'what does this mean?' help text. See the image below.

[image]